# Optimize a query for creating a ranking in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm creating an application where users do workouts. They pass on their results via an app, and these results are stored in an SQL Server database. Results are saved in this way in a SQL Server table:

[image: SQL Server table]

I want to write a query to create a ranking based on the best score of each user. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT id, 
       workout_id, 
       level_id, 
       a.user_id, 
       total_time, 
       score, 
       datetime_added
FROM nodefit_rankings_fitness as a INNER JOIN
    (
     SELECT user_id, 
            MAX(score) AS MAXSCORE 
     FROM nodefit_rankings_fitness 
     GROUP BY user_id
    ) AS lookup
ON  lookup.user_id = a.user_id
    AND 
    lookup.MAXSCORE  =  a.score
ORDER BY score DESC, 
         datetime_added DESC
```

This generates this ranking:

[image: SQL Server]

The problem is that if a user has achieved the same maximum score a number of times, he will appear multiple times in the ranking. The query must be adjusted so that when a user has the same maximum score a few times, only the result of the last attempt (based on the `datetime_added` column) is displayed in the rankings.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a solution myself. Help is certainly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your sample data as a CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for easy testing? Images are kind of hard to copy from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about performance, you should also try a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT id, workout_id, level_id, a.user_id, total_time, score, datetime_added
FROM nodefit_rankings_fitness nrf
WHERE nrf.id = (SELECT TOP (1) nrf2.id
                FROM nodefit_rankings_fitness nrf2
                WHERE nrf2.user_id = nrf.user_id
                ORDER BY nrf2.score DESC
               )
ORDER BY score DESC, datetime_added DESC;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `nodefit_rankings_fitness(user_id, score desc, id)`.

Comment: @SvenNijs . . . The `score` should not be compared to the `id`.  I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks! This query seems to be the most performant. I have one more question... When a certain user submits a new workout, I want to check his ranking based on the last submitted workout, compared to the best performance of other users. So suppose user 2 adds a new workout, and his score is, say, 25, what is his current ranking based on that new performance? Maybe I have to post a new question but i think it must be a small change on this query...

Comment: @SvenNijs . . . You should ask new questions as a *new* question rather than in a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I did that.

Answer (score 1):

Window functions make stuff like this easy. Something like:

```
SELECT id, workout_id, level_id, user_id, total_time, score, datetime_added
FROM (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY score DESC, datetime_added DESC) AS rn
      FROM nodefit_rankings_fitness) AS a
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY score DESC, datetime_added DESC;
```

Comment: @SvenNijs Then please mark the suggestion as an answer. Because that is how SO is designed to work - people with questions look for answers; when they don't find them they ask.

Comment: @SMor The answer from GordonLinoff seems to be a little more performant... Many thanks, unfortunately I can only mark 1 post as correct answer...