# Create a MS SQL Server query to determine ranking

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm creating an application where users do workouts. They pass on their results via an app, and these results are stored in an SQL Server database. Results are saved in this way in a SQL Server table:

[image]

I want to write a query to create a ranking based on the best score of each user. This is what I have so far (thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56492108/optimize-a-query-for-creating-a-ranking-in-ms-sql-server)):

```
SELECT id, workout_id, level_id, user_id, total_time, score, datetime_added
FROM nodefit_rankings_fitness nrf
WHERE nrf.id = (SELECT TOP (1) nrf2.id
                FROM nodefit_rankings_fitness nrf2
                WHERE nrf2.user_id = nrf.user_id
                ORDER BY nrf2.score DESC
               )
ORDER BY score DESC, datetime_added DESC;
```

This generates following, where a ranking is created based on the best score for a user:

[image]

When a certain user submits a new workout, I want to check his ranking based on the last submitted workout, compared to the best performances of other users. So suppose user_id 2 adds a new workout, and his score is, say, 12, what is his current ranking based on that new performance? In that case he has a second place in this table. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @CurrentUser INT = 5;

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT id, 
           workout_id, 
           level_id, 
           user_id, 
           total_time, 
           score, 
           datetime_added,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY score DESC, datetime_added DESC) rowID
    FROM nodefit_rankings_fitness 
    WHERE user_id <> @CurrentUser
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 
           workout_id, 
           level_id, 
           user_id, 
           total_time, 
           score, 
           datetime_added,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datetime_added DESC) rowID
    FROM nodefit_rankings_fitness 
    WHERE user_id = @CurrentUser

)
SELECT *
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) AS RankID
FROM DataSource
WHERE rowID = 1
ORDER BY RankID
```